# Run shell command in mongo aggregation using python file

Tags: python, json, mongodb, shell

I need to run a mongo aggregation command in the shell using python script. How can I achieve this? This is my try

```
import subprocess 
printj = 'aggregation_query'  
cmd ='mongo --quiet mydb --eval',"'",printj,"'",' > output_traffic.json'  
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

It gives an error

```
File "shellcmd.py", line 15, in <module>
    subprocess.call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Why can not you run aggregation framework in python through python, not through mongoshell?

Comment: Akso, give us the complete traceback

Comment: You're not splitting up arguments, so you need to use [`shell=True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments): `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the `mongo` shell using `subprocess`, just import pymongo and connect to the MongoDB server directly. [Examples of running aggregation queries from PyMongo are in the documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html).

Comment: Example link seems to be deprecated, refer to the official pymongo docs: [Examples of aggregation queries](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/aggregation.html)